# Expected number of trials when after each failed trial the probability of success changes

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value

Say we need to look for a number $k$ in an array. Array is from 1 to 10.
We pick a number $x$ with uniform probability of 1/10. Now $x$ is not equal to $k$, so we discard it (without replacement). Now we pick another number with probability of 1/9 and so on.

What is the expected number of trials after which we will find the $k$ in array?

Answer (score 1):

Keep these in mind and you will soon find the answer:

1. You know that the maximum number of draws is 10.
2. If $M = 4$ means that you find ball $k$ on the 4th draw, then the expected number of draws is $\sum_{m=1}^{10} m \times P(M=m)$
3. $P(M=m)$ is the probability that you *do not* find ball $k$ on draws $1, 2, \dots, m-1$ and *do* find it on draw $m$.

Comment: So basically we add all the probabilities of failure and then add the probability of success at the end. 
For eg: we have 9/10 probability to not find the ball K in first draw, then 8/9 in the second draw but at third draw we have 1/8 chances to finally get it. But how is that calculating the expected number of draws when I know that I am drawing ball K at 3rd draw? I am confused here.

Comment: My steps are listed out of order: steps 2 and 3 should be swapped. Anyway, you're describing step 3. You repeat that for finding the ball on the first draw, finding it on the second, the third, the fourth, etc. Then you combine them as shown in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

We can find out via simulation:

```py
trials_needed = []
# run the simulation 100k times
for i in range(100000):
    options = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    k = np.random.choice(options)
    x = np.random.choice(options)
    i = 1
    while x != k:
        options.remove(x)
        x = np.random.choice(options)
        i += 1
    trials_needed.append(i)
```

The distribution of trials needed until we find $k$ is $\operatorname{Uniform}(1,10)$:
[image: Distribution of trials needed]
and the expected number of trials is $\approx5.5$.

If you were looking for a more theoretical way to get to the answer, Wesley's answer will be more useful. That being said, I find that simulation is always helpful - at the very least you can use it to check whether you got your analytical solution right!